# Scala Mohiva play-silhouette-seed get social data

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, silhouette

I'm using https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed
I want to take from VK some data like City, country etc. but I don't know which way I should do it. It would be perfect if I can do something like this https://vk.com/dev/users.get and receive JSON which I should parse to my user's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Silhouette you have two possibilities.

**Social profile builders and parsers**

With this you can extend an existing provider to fetch more fields and to build the data directly into your model.

This is documented in detail on the [project website](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/providers#social-profile-builders-and-parsers).

**Note**: The VK provider has a slightly different [method signature](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/providers/oauth2/VKProvider.scala#L106) for the parse method, because it gets the `OAuth2Info` passed additionally. With this you can also query the API with the Play WS API directly in the profile parser, if the data isn't already contained in the [default API call](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/providers/oauth2/VKProvider.scala#L169). (The auth info should definitely be passed to the other providers too. I'll create a ticket for this)

**Query the API with the stored access token**

If you store the access token(OAuth2Info) then you can query the API with the Play WS API and merge the data into your user data.